# Install 2 websites on my server static box adress (IPV4)

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have an ipv4 address that is linked to my internet provider box ( e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and I have installed a site on this website. So when I reach the address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx I land on this website.
But I have a second version of this website and I want it to put on an address like app.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (to take example of a site with a domain name like app.thesite.com)

Is there a way to do this? to put my second website on a port xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8546 e.g

Thanks !
Gum

Comment: On Apache? Something else? https://geekflare.com/multiple-domains-on-one-server-with-apache-nginx/

Comment: Yes. This is possible, and can be done a number of ways - your question does not provide adequate information for more specifics.

Comment: Thank to you two !
I'm just starting networking I will look further !